# NuxtJs SSR configuration

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

i have a question about nuxt js SSR configuration. I think nuxtjs is SSR in default. But SEO experts say my project is CSR. I make some research and learn that nuxt have modes **'spa'** and **'universal'** In my `nuxt.config.js` file i found this line of code:

```
export default {
      mode: 'spa', 
....
```

if i will make it 'universal' my project will work SSR? or i need to make extra some configurations?

```
  export default {
          mode: 'universal', 
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be enough. You can read more [here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-client-only/).

Be aware that some components may not work with SSR. For these, you have the `<client-only>` component to render it only on the client-side. [Official doc](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/#single-page-applications-).

Comment: Sorry about the links. [SSR - SPA](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/#single-page-applications-) [Client only component](https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-client-only/)